# Dart/flutter: How to fix "Unexpected character" error when serializing/de-serializing a map<> to json?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Can you please lend a hand and show how to serialize and de-serialize a class that contains a map of objects to/from json in dart?

Here's an example of a simple data class:

```
class SimpleData {
  int _blah;
  String _str;

  SimpleData([this._blah, this._str]);

  SimpleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _blah = json['b'];
    _str = json['s'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'b' : _blah,
    's' : _str,
  };
}
```

And here's how `SimpleData` is used in a map:

```
class MapTest {
  Map<String, SimpleData> _mapHell = Map<String, SimpleData>();

  MapTest() {
    _mapHell['1'] = SimpleData(42, "Astfgl");
    _mapHell['666'] = SimpleData(1234, "Vassenego");
  }

  MapTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _mapHell = jsonDecode(json['coworkers']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'coworkers' : jsonEncode(_mapHell),
  };
}
```

Calling: `print(mapTestInstance.toJson().toString());` will output:

```
{coworkers: {"1":{"b":42,"s":"Astfgl"},"666":{"b":1234,"s":"Vassenego"}}}
```

Trying to de-serialize this, fails because `coworkers` is supposed to be surrounded by `""`. The error message reads:

```
I/flutter (10196): Unexpected character (at character 2)
I/flutter (10196): {coworkers: {"1":{"b":42,"s":"Astfgl"},"666":{"b":1234,"s":"Vassenego"}}}
```

Now the question is, what's wrong with the code above? And how can it be fixed?

Oddly enough, using json is surprisingly cumbersome in Dart/Flutter, so your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer but recommendation: use the already existing Json Serializable package instead of parsing Json manually, also see freezed it is good too :
https://pub.dev/packages/freezed https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I just took a look at json_serializable and from the description it seems it could do it, but how are you supposed to use this? The documentation is utterly pointless, so I'll stick with encoding it by hand...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can see `MapTest` class in full code

code snippet

```
String jsonString = '''
    {"coworkers": {"1":{"b":42,"s":"Astfgl"},"666":{"b":1234,"s":"Vassenego"}}}
    ''';

MapTest mapTest = mapTestFromJson(jsonString);

print(mapTest.coworkers["1"].b);
print(mapTest.coworkers["666"].s);

String str = mapTestToJson(mapTest);
print(str);
```

output

```
I/flutter (26208): 42
I/flutter (26208): Vassenego
I/flutter (26208): {"coworkers":{"1":{"b":42,"s":"Astfgl"},"666":{"b":1234,"s":"Vassenego"}}}
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

MapTest mapTestFromJson(String str) => MapTest.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String mapTestToJson(MapTest data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MapTest {
  Map<String, Coworker> coworkers;

  MapTest({
    this.coworkers,
  });

  factory MapTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MapTest(
        coworkers: Map.from(json["coworkers"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Coworker>(k, Coworker.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "coworkers": Map.from(coworkers)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class Coworker {
  int b;
  String s;

  Coworker({
    this.b,
    this.s,
  });

  factory Coworker.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Coworker(
        b: json["b"],
        s: json["s"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "b": b,
        "s": s,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    String jsonString = '''
    {"coworkers": {"1":{"b":42,"s":"Astfgl"},"666":{"b":1234,"s":"Vassenego"}}}
    ''';

    MapTest mapTest = mapTestFromJson(jsonString);

    print(mapTest.coworkers["1"].b);
    print(mapTest.coworkers["666"].s);

    String str = mapTestToJson(mapTest);
    print(str);

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your **'coworkers' : jsonEncode(_mapHell),**
to

```
'"coworkers"' : jsonEncode(_mapHell),
```

example

```
class MapTest {
  Map<String, SimpleData> _mapHell = Map<String, SimpleData>();

  MapTest() {
    _mapHell['1'] = SimpleData(42, "Astfgl");
    _mapHell['666'] = SimpleData(1234, "Vassenego");
  }

  MapTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _mapHell = jsonDecode(json['coworkers']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    '"coworkers"' : jsonEncode(_mapHell),
  };
}
```